# Word 365 (online version) -- where is the document revision history (like google docs has?)

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, office365

I found [this article](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/view-previous-versions-of-office-files-5c1e076f-a9c9-41b8-8ace-f77b9642e2c2), but when I have the doc open in Word 365, there is no clock button to be seen, and the File | Info area does not seem to have an option for the version history.

The file is saved on one drive.

Comment: Have you tried using the Office 2016 instructions?

Comment: @Ramhound Note, this question is about Word 365. I looked in help there and do not see anything about version history or revision history.

Comment: I understand what your asking about but there are two programs called Word 365.  One is an online version of Word, the other is a subscription based version of Word, the subscription based version is actually just the current build of Word 2016.  I am trying to verify which version you actually have

Comment: @Ramhound Sorry, I did not understand the issue. Title of OP enhanced.